# if else statement Mule 3

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

I want to set a variable based on the output in Mule 3.

For example the check I want to do is if there is any payload
I want to set the var value to this ${http.path.one} else
${http.path.two}.
In Mule 4 it can be done in multiple ways but in Mule 3 seems little tricky. Has anyone an idea how to implement this in Mule 3?

Comment: You can go with when and otherwise( Condition operation) in mule 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mule 3 DataWeave you can use when/otherwise instead of Mule 4 if/else. To access the properties use the p() function. Depending on the exact payload and the condition you need you may need to tweak the expression for the condition.

Example:

```js
p('http.path.two') when (payload != null) otherwise p('http.path.one')
```